# XIomi redmi note adb usb debug drivers

Tags: adb, driver, usb-debugging

I tried many ADB Driver Softwares of Xaiomi redmi note but i am unable to use USB-debugging mode while running a real app from android studio

Comment: Any Solution as I am also not able to connect..my device is Redmi Note 3. Please guide

Answer (score 1):

No need to install external ADB Driver for Redmi,Redmi already Provide with device. The device may not be visible for debugging if it is in MTP mode. Redmi 3S work in charging Mode in win 8.

```
This can be change 
 1. Go Setting 
 2. Additional Setting
 3. Developers Option
 4. Select USB Configuration
 5. Select Charging Only
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're having problem on Windows, perform the following

1. On your Windows desktop, Go to your Control Panel then Device Manager.
2. You should see Android Phone under Other Devices with a Yellow ! mark on it.
3. Right click on it and choose "Update Driver Software"
4. Choose "Browse my computer", then "Let me pick from a list."
5. If you see categories, select "Android Device", then select "MOT Composite ADB Interface".
6. The driver will install and you can now run the update with ADB.

Let me know if you have issues.