# ADB is not recognizing my Redmi Note device

Tags: android, adb

ADB is not recognizing my Redmi Note device. I am using windows 8

[image: Device manager showing device]

Also when I use below command in CMD, 
adb devices 
it is displaying

[image: CMD not showing device]

I followed the procedure in below link,

[Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964862/xiomi-redmi-note-adb-usb-debug-drivers?answertab=active#tab-top Here I given suggestions

Comment: [check there i have given solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964862/xiomi-redmi-note-adb-usb-debug-drivers?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For the Redmi Note ADB drivers, you have to go through this hoop. I am certain it is the same with all MI phones or maybe for all non-Google mfg phones, I am not sure. First of all if you connect the device with USB cable and USB Debugging off, you will see that Windows 8 loads a generic driver for you to copy on/off files to the phone and SD storage. This will appear when the USB cable is first plugged in and appears as a device icon under Control Panel, Device Manager, Portable Devices, HM Note(or the device you are working with).

Go to the phone and switch on USB Debugging in the Developer section of your phone. Notice that an additional item appears as an undefined device now in the device manager list, it will have the yellow exclamation mark and it may not have the same name of the phone listed as you saw under Portable Devices. Ignore this item for the moment. Now, without doing anything to the phone (it should be already in USB debug mode) go back to the Portable Devices in Device Manager and right-click the HM Note or whatever phone you are working with that is listed there without the exclamation mark (listed under Portable Devices). Right click on the icon under Portable Devices. On that icon select Properties, Details, and under the pull down, select Hardware IDs and copy down what you see.

For Redmi Note I get:

```
USB\VID_2717&PID_1218&REV_0216&MI_00
USB\VID_2717&PID_1218&MI_00
```

(Note if you do this out of turn, the HW ID will be different with the phone USB debugging turned off. You want to copy the value that it changes to when the USB debugging is ON)

Now do as the instructions say above, of course customizing the lines you add the the INF file with those relating to your own phone, not the Nexus 10. Here is what to customize; when you downloaded the SDK you should have a file structure expanded from the ZIP such as this:

```
\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver
```

Find the file named: `android_winusb.inf` in the usb_driver folder Make a copy of it and name it anything, such as `redmi.inf`.

Edit the `redmi.inf` and add the lines as instructed above only modified for your particular phone. For example, for the HM Note, I added the following 2 lines as instructed in the 2 locations as instructed.

```
;HM Note
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_2717&PID_1218&REV_0216&MI_0
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_2717&PID_1218&MI_00
```

Now go back up to the unknown device that appeared in Device Manager when you switched on device USB debugging and right click on this item (has yellow exclamation mark), right click on it and then select Update Driver Software, and then Browse My Computer, Let Me Pick, click on the Have Disk button and browse to find the Redmi.inf. Continue to agree to all the prompts warning you it might not be the right driver. As the final step, Windows should have identified the device as Android ADB Interface and once that is done, you should be able to go back, open your CMD window and run the command "adb devices" as instructed in this tutorial and now you should see that the phone is now discovered and communicating.

I found this at [ADB No Devices Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721778/adb-no-devices-found?rq=1)

Comment: I have a Redmi Note4. I created the redmi.inf file but I'm not sure where I should copy and paste the Hardware IDs. Just anything? Which two locations are you referring to? @dnyaneshwar

Comment: Weird. It worked for me by merely copying the .inf file and naming it ``redmi.inf``. I didn't have to copy any values to the new file. Is this the case for anyone else? Otherwise, I'd assume this was a false positive and it started working based on something I did before. Cheers anyway.

Comment: @santafebound can you please explain more about what you did ? i have redmi note 4 too and nothing works for me

Comment: I was actually looking for this comment to delete it. I thought I solved my problem but I did not.

Comment: Works for redmi note 5. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Follow the below step to resolve adb shell not showing device issue.

1) Go to **About Phone**, and tap **MIUI version** for 7 to 8 times. This is to enable developer mode.

2) Got to **Additional Settings** -> **Developer options**. Enable **USB debugging**. And set **MIDI** in **Select USB configuration**. If you need apk installation via adb, then enable **Install via USB** also.

Answer (score 8):

This solution worked for me :

Try Installing the PC Suite that came with Redmi Note and it will install all the necessary drivers for the mobile to work properly with PC Suite ;) . And after that check the connection with ADB it works fine.

Answer (score 7):

I found a workaround without installing anything. Follow these steps:

1. Turn on Developer options.
2. Open the developer options.
3. Turn on the android debugging.
4. Scroll to bottom of the list.
5. There will be an option called "Turn on MIUI optimisation" which will be turned on by default, turn it off. the device will restart.
   Voila! Your adb should be able to detect your mi device now.

PS: I found this solution a year back but now I don't remember where.:)

Comment: I follow all steps except step 3 turning on android debugging then everything is okay

Comment: I forgot it after two years and had to look for that again...

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the hidden Developer Options on your Redmi Note. To do so:

1. On your Redmi phone, find and launch the Settings app.
2. Tap General settings.
3. Tap About phone.
4. Tap "MIUI version" for 7 times.
   Once you reached the 7th times, you’ll see the “You are now a developer” message appears on screen.
   You are now a developer.
5. Once turned on, you can tap Developer options on the General Settings screen to access a list of options which deemed to be mainly useful to the developers.

Lastly, you can do a factory reset to hide the Developer options.

After the above steps, go to command prompt and run adb devices command. It should fetch the device id for connected redmi note phone.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't work out by trying out solutions mentioned by others, then on top of that Try installing and running **MI PC-SUITE** from official Mi website [HERE](http://pcsuite.mi.com/). Then try debugging again and you will see your device name in the list of available devices/options to run the app.

Comment: installing and running MI PC-SUITE helped. :-)

Answer (score 1):

revoke all USB-debugging options and reenable it again in MI phones.

Setting -> Developer options -> Revoke all USB-debugging -> Then enable USB debugging

Disable MIUI optimizations