# Android Studio does not recognize my Xiaomi Redmi Note 3

Tags: android, android-studio, drivers

When I try to "run" app via Android Studios, my Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 doesnt pop up in the list. However, it does show up in my PC file explorer.

Things I've done;

-tried to install both Xiaomi's own usb drivers and Google's usb drivers, with the same result; "No newer drivers are available"

-enabled usb debugging, makes no different

-switching between PTP and MTP mode

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Is your mobile available as a storage in my computer?

Comment: Which operating system are you in ? If on linux, open up a terminal and type "sudo adb devices" and post the output

Comment: Im on windows 10, and yes, I can browse trough all the files on my phone via the pc, and it does recognize it as "Redmi Note 3"

Comment: any leads yet? I am having the same problem and sail on the same boat as yours.

Comment: Do you work in Windows/Ubuntu/Mac...? if you are on ubuntu/linux then you would have to add your device ID in the rules file.

Comment: Got the same with a "MI MAX 3" device. Using a usb-c cable (from iPad Pro). Oh it worked a minute ago and then decided it should not work any more the minute later. Update: I changed usb-c port on my Macbook Pro and voila. WTF

Answer (score 57):

=> **For Enabling to developer Mode In Redmi Note 3 :**

1: Go to Setting.

2: Click to "About phone" option.

3: Press ***7 times*** to "MIUI version" option.

now you will see a Toast message *"now you are developer"*.

=> **Now you should install to Mi PC Suite** from [this](http://pcsuite.mi.com/) .

1: Install the pc suite with connected your redmi.

2: Now go on Permission in setting and click "install via USB".

=>**For Enabling USB Debugging :**

1: Open Settings > Additional settings > Developer options.

2: Firstly enable to developer options then go below and find USB Debugging and      enable it.

3: When your pc suite open then again repeat disable and enable to USB Debugging

**For Redmi 4a also follow :**

Open Settings > Additional settings > Developer options > Select USB Configuration > MTP.

Comment: Worked for Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro running Miui 8 Global 6.11.3 Beta

Comment: installing that PC suit is the key, and the lucky part for me was it didn't needed Admin privileges

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101987/android-studio-does-not-recognize-my-xiaomi-redmi-note-3/48397964#48397964

Comment: for installing pc suite was unnecessary

Answer (score 30):

I am not sure if you are always looking for a solution. However, I had the same problem, and to fix it, just try the following steps (it works for me):

1. Go to Settings > Additional settings > Developer options
2. Disable the "Turn on MUI optimization"
3. Reboot your phone

It should work after rebooting your device.
Good luck

Comment: Perfect, Why is this answer far down?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101987/android-studio-does-not-recognize-my-xiaomi-redmi-note-3/48397964#48397964

Answer (score 18):

Xiaomi interface has a lot of "locks".
To use your Xiaomi device to test your apps you need to:

- enable developer mode:

  - Settings > About Phone > MIUI version.
  - Tap the MIUI version message until you receive a message telling you that you are a developer.
- enable usb debugging (inside the developer menu).
- enable fast-booting (I don't know if this one is necessary).
- install the Mi PC Suite.
- Use a USB port from behind of your computer.
- allow third party's apps on your device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101987/android-studio-does-not-recognize-my-xiaomi-redmi-note-3/48397964#48397964

Comment: you would also need their own charging cable for reason, otherwise it fails to detect on any standard micro USB cable.

Answer (score 8):

- Go To Settings > Additional Settings > Developer Options
- Now Enable these options

  - USB Debugging
  - Install Via USB
  - Select USB Configuration to MIDI

Comment: Above steps worked for my redmi 5 smartphone. Its really frustrating to try so many options and figuring out which option to worked.

Comment: Select USB Configuration to MIDI (This one is annoying but important). Making this configuration done resolved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to Additional settings
3. Go to Developer options
4. Disable the "Turn on MUI optimization"
5. Reboot your phone

It will work

Answer (score 6):

I Found this answer on Quora 
(Worked like a Charm in my case , tried other methods previously but they didn't work for me)

COMPILATION OF ALL POSSIBLE STEPS.TRUST ME IT WORKS!

I would like to improve this answer. Once you have enabled being a developer

1.Settings->About Phone->MIUI version .Click on it for seven times.

2.Go to Additional settings->Developer Options.Now you will have to enable two options in this.

a.USB debugging

IN developer options,Scroll to the end to find TURN OFF MIUI OPTIMIZATION.And you may need to reboot your phone.(no issues,nothing will happen).

And if it says you have temporary issues, disable Wi-Fi and enable your mobile network.Even then if it does not allow,

3.Settings->under APP SETTINGS section->Permissions.

4. Click on the top right corner and slide over the option INSTALL VIA USB.
5. Now don't forget to go back to Settings->Developer Options->Install via USB(enable).

When all these steps are done together, it works perfectly else,

In your android studio,

Go to FILE->SETTINGS->BUILD,EXECUTION,DEVELOPMENT.Under this,uncheck enable instant run.

I've been trying to look for the possible answers for almost a year now on my MI note 4.And it finally worked today.Happy to share.Enjoy.

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Answer (score 4):

For Xiaomi Redmi 6, in Developer options do the following:

- Enable USB debugging
- Enable Install via USB
- Disable Turn on MIUI optimization
- **On Select USB configuration select MIDI** (*this is what solved the problem for me*)

Also, take a look at this question: [ADB is not recognizing my Redmi Note device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488295/adb-is-not-recognizing-my-redmi-note-device)

Comment: On Select USB configuration select MIDI : this works for me thank yu.

Comment: For Redmi 8, I needed to install and/or update `Samsung-USB-Driver` to version `1.7.13.0` and at last works!

Answer (score 3):

I bumped into the same issue

Run below on terminal to find your VENDOR ID;

```
lsusb
```

This will display information about USB buses in the system and the devices connected to them.Then, find your phones vendor id (it will be probably without any company names) and type,

```
sudo gedit ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

and your `adb_usb.ini` file should look like:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
# ie 0x2207
0x<!!!Your Vendor ID here!!!>
```

Disconnected and reconnected device and also needed to run below commands on terminal;

```
sudo adb kill-server && adb start-server
```

And the device was detected.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a problem with connection of Xiaomi Redmi 4 Pro (I hope problem is common for Note 3 too) to Android Studio.

I did next steps:

1. First of all enable Developer Mode. I won't dublicate how to do it, as it was described here many times.
2. To solve problem with ADB Interface driver, I've installed Mi PC Suite - MiSetup3.2.1.3111_2717 ([link to download](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24572369242686434))
3. As output from **adb devices** command still shown me empty list of connected devices, **I tried to use original USB cabel which came with my phone** instead of some Xiaomi's USB cabel bougth earlier, and it helps! Phone successfully connected to Android Studio and I installed my test apps!

Hope it will help you guys too.

Comment: Marked as a solution for the tip about the cable!

Answer (score 2):

**MI Devices** developer mode enable option is quite different. Please refer the below screenshots for the detailed understanding.

In the MI Devices developer mode options stays inside the **Additional Setting**

[image: Mi Developer Mode Additional Settings]

[image: Mi Developer Options]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just

1. goto Additional Settings > Developer Option > there at the bottom just **turn off MIUI optimization.**

**Then**

2. Enable:

   - USB debugging
   - Install via USB
   - USB debugging (Security settings)

**Worked for me.**
cheers

Comment: USB debugging (Security settings) this helped for me in Redmi 4.

Answer (score 2):

Settings > About phone > keep tapping ‘ MIUI version ‘ until it says you’re a developer.

Settings > Additional settings > developer options> toggle ‘USB debugging'

Settings > Additional settings > Developer options> toggle ‘Install via USB'

TRY THIS ONE.THIS WILL WORK.

Answer (score 1):

In some rare cases,the problem is windows "Administrative Templates"

My Xiaomi redmi 2 can't connect with Android Studio although I've done Everything That people say above.

But in my Case I found a solution :

1. put gpedit.msc in windows command
2. go to "Administrative Templates" -> "System" -> "Removable Storage Access"
3. Disable:

   ```
    -Removable Disk: Deny execute access
    -Removable Disk: Deny read access
    -Removable Disk: Deny write access
    -All Removable Storage classes: Deny all access
   ```
4. Plug on your device
5. Run app

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry dude .....
first turn on USB debugging...
then Turn on Install via USB...
just turn off your MIUI optimization ....
then it'll ask to restart...
restart your mobile and then it should work....

I hope this will help... 
and it worked on my MI 3s prime
**application installation failed  message failed to establish session ....**

Answer (score 0):

Update your MIUI version to 7.3.5.0 and you should install drivers in your pc.
[Driver link](http://en.miui.com/thread-33320-1-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ADB interface wasn't updated properly.

Try this: [ADB is not recognizing my Android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31489453/7030003)
or https://stackoverflow.com/a/31489453/7030003

This worked for me!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**"Install via USB"** wont work if your Xiaomi phone is running MIUI 8 or above. Looks like when you try to Enable this option, your phone trys to connect to some chinese server and fails.

I got a work around and it worked for me. Idea is to connect to Chinese-Shanghai server through VPN. Try the following:

1. Install **PlexVPN** from Playstore and login into it. You will a 24 hr free VPN service.
2. Select **China-Shanghai server** and connect.
3. From developer option in your Xiaomi phone, **Enable "Install via USB"**.

You can then disconnect the VPN and logout from PlexVPN.

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make sure that you have **DEVELOPER MODE** on. To turn on,

1. Go to **About phone**
2. Tap the **MIUI version** until it shows the message that "You are now a developer."
3. When successful, you can now access **developer options** in **Additional settings** in the main Settings.
4. Go to **developer options** and enable USB debugging mode.

Secondly, to make sure it allows your phone to used via ADB. Download the necessary USB driver.

This can be done via Android Studio by going to **SDK Manager** --> **Tools** --> **Google USB Drivers** --> Install this.

### To avoid the "INSTALLATION_CANCELLED_BY_USER" error, do this:

1. Go to the "Security" application and tap "Options" at top right corner.
2. Scroll down to "Feature Settings" group, and look for "Permissions"
3. At there switch off "Install via USB" option, which manages installation of the apps via USB and doesn't allow it.

On Latest Redmi Device,

- Settings > Additional Settings > Developer Options > Developer
  options: Check the Install via USB option.

Once installed, you will be able to use your Xiaomi device for App Testing.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works then do these steps:

1. Turn on USB Debugging in Developer options.
2. Turn On USB Tethering too.

For USB Debugging go to:
Settings > Additional Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging

For USB Tethering go to:
Settings > More > USB Tethering

Now it should work. Mine works.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

My Redmi Note 4 had a same issue but after installing HiSuite everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Redmi 5 Plus : Make sure to also download and install the Mi Pc Suite.

Answer (score 0):

100% your MI phone will be detected by android studio by using following steps

1) first you have to turn on developer mode 
2) turn on usb debugging

3) Install MI ADB driver from below link you must to login first before downloading
https://c.mi.com/thread-1625831-1-1.html

4) Your phone will be shown in Android studio...Enjoy

Comment: The page is not an official source of the drivers and has download links that are broken. Consider using an official source instead (or at the very least, one that works!).

Answer (score 0):

**For all the Mac Users**

1. Just follow the instructions in one of the other answers, for example [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39406501/4826457) from [Bhunnu Baba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5143082/bhunnu-baba).
2. Since *Mi PC Suite* isn't available for Mac, use an alternative software. I tried [SyncMate](https://www.sync-mac.com) and it worked like a charm. An important thing is that you also have to install the *SyncMate App* on your Xiaomi.

PS: I use a *Xiaomi Redmi 9t*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using a Redmi 9, and it was not being monitored by USB in my Mac.
Solution: Settings > Developer Options > Standard USB Configuration > Select File Transfer

Answer (score 0):

In a recent Xiaomi update, there are now twice USB-Debugging options available. In both version, USB-Debugging needs to be activated in order to connect successfully with Android Studio.