# Android Studio does not recognize my Xiaomi Redmi 4a miui 9.6.5.0

Tags: android, usb

When I try to "run" app via Android Studios, my Xiaomi Redmi 4a does not show up in my Android Studio.

Things I've done;

- tried to install both Xiaomi's own USB drivers and Google's USB drivers, with the same result; "No newer drivers are available."
- enabled USB debugging makes no different
- switching between PTP and MTP mode

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio does not recognize my Xiaomi Redmi Note 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101987/android-studio-does-not-recognize-my-xiaomi-redmi-note-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,
Disable windows signature

windows 7
http://en.miui.com/thread-237673-1-1.html

windows 8
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/disabling-driver-signature-on-windows-8/disabling-signed-driver-enforcement-on-windows-8

windows 10 
https://ph.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38288/~/windows-10%3A-disable-signed-driver-enforcement

then download this
http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

It will work, i have similar issues with LG smart Phone.
Windows doesn't recognize mobile sometime we need to disable signature

Comment: bro i tried it but unfortunately it did't work.My mi 4a is showing in others computers but not showing in my android studio.

Comment: Oh, have you disable windows signature ? After that have you launch adb.exe file to install your device drivers ? which operating system you are using ?
.

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 and where can i launch adb.exe file?

Comment: Install automatic driver installation from this link http://adbdriver.com/downloads/, after disabling signature launch this application to install your drivers.

Comment: Thanx bro i followed your steps and its now showing my device.May god bless u with health wealth and prosperity. But i am having this issue now **when i run the application** it shows me this message **Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?**

Comment: Good to here that, May ALLAH bless you with best !
Yes bro, you need to remove apk first.......then reinstall it.
Please mark this answer right one.....

Comment: ok bro .I removed the apk file from my mobile also removed from app\build\outputs\apk but it is showing same message again.Is there an other solution for this? **https://imgur.com/1G7NfAy**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641670/adb-install-failure-install-canceled-by-user
Try this, hope it work !!

Comment: ok bro but my one option in develpor option is off and that is install via usb but it needs mi account to turn it ON but i dont want to sign up to mi account.Is there any other solution for this to turn it on without signing in to mi account ? and i installed plex vpn but it did not worked.