# Android Studio Shows No Connected Device When I try to run my app on a real device

Tags: android, windows

I am trying to run an android app i just created using Android Studio IDE. I am using a MTK device, i have downloaded and installed so many adbs but still can't solve the problem. My Laptop is running Windows 7(32Bits).

Comment: Have you enabled USB Debugging option in Mobile ?

Comment: Did you install its usb driver?

Comment: Please visit this link, it might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468499/android-studio-does-not-recognize-my-xiaomi-redmi-4a-miui-9-6-5-0/52468635#52468635

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)

Answer (score 0):

Use external android emulators like Leapdroid, GenyMotion, etc. I suggest you to install Leapdroid. It is very easy to use. 
[U can download Leapdroid by the following link][1]

![1]: https://leapdroid.en.softonic.com/download

Comment: Thanks for the emu suggestions but Am not speaking of emulators. My Nexus 5 emulator works just fine, i want to run my app on a real android device not an emulator.