# Redmi 9 and Android Studio - Installation via USB is disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, usb

1. Android studio successfully recognized my device Xiaomi Redmi 9A

[image]

2. I found in my device 3 options related with USB debugging and turn on its. Forth option I try to set on and off, no result. This is all developer options of Redmi9 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18AOk8QvcOWNTKwagifWFJUfohZdJ6bm6

[image]

However I receive message - Installation via USB is disabled.

Comment: Just to make sure you hit 7 times on the `build number` to unlock the developer mode

Comment: @Zain, thank you,  I try to hit, but receive message - no need, you are already a developer

Answer (score 0):

Redmi 9 (9A etc) has driver issues when enabling USB debug, plus many of the dev options are locked and need to be unlocked via a specific procedure that the phone will present itself. Almost all drivers required for Redmi phones,(mediatek,qualcomm,android) are very finicky.
**Have you fully unlocked your redmi device(cpu)?** **It requires a sim with mobile data and a Mi account.**

Here are similar posts you can try but didnt work for me:
[ADB is not recognizing my Redmi Note device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488295/adb-is-not-recognizing-my-redmi-note-device)